# How to make React Flexbox stretch to full screen height

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to create a React app that is optimized for mobile and am doing most of the layout using flexbox. I'm having trouble forcing the main container of my app to automatically expand to the full device height.

What rules can I apply, specifically to my html container `<div id="react-app"></div>` and my main app container `<App></App>` so that they will always stretch to the full screen height, even when their children wouldn't force them to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
height:100vh
```

for your App component, but it can looks not perfect on iOS Safari. Also you can set

```
        html, body, #reactapp, .App {
          height: 100%;
        }
       .App {
         display: flex;
        }
```

Comment: Neither of those seem to be doing the trick, any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: @PatrickConnors check all tags from html to application tag, all of it must have 100% height. If one of them will not have proper height, the next tags will have 100% of this tag, not the full screen.

Comment: All of the html elements are now the full height of the screen. When inspected, my outermost react component has the style "display:flex" applied to it but it still does not stretch to the full height when hovered over.

Comment: @PatrickConnors does the app component has 100% height too? Also check if all parent elements has display:block, or if it have display: 'flex' it should have align-items:stretch property

Comment: The align-items: stretch along with setting height to 100vh within the flexbox component did the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[patelarpan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50421520) seems to be the most concise solution:

> You can achieve this by using "vh" units, and it's a more effective way than using percentages because you don't need to set every parent height to 100% if you want the child's height to be 100%.
>
> ```
> .columnContainer { 
>    display: flex; 
>    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
> }
> ```
>
> Here is an example of the 60px app bar height being excluded from the viewport height.

I replaced the height line in patelarpan's example with this, since I don't have an app bar:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score -3):

## root > [data-reactroot] { height: 100% } in your CSS should work.

Or just the tag itself:

[data-reactroot] { ... }