# Making a flexbox container height 100% in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flex box container of 3 columns. 3 column part works. But I want them to take complete available height excluding the app bar.

[image: Demo SS]

Css

```
.columnContainer {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;

}
.leftContainer {
    flex : 1;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}

.rightContainer {
    flex : 1;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.middleContainer {
    flex : 3;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

I have added 200px just to show those columns on screen. Tried 100% but it didnt show anything.

And in react js part,

```
<div>
        <HomeBar />
        <div className={'columnContainer'}>
            <div className={'leftContainer'}>

            </div>
            <div className={'middleContainer'}>

            </div>
            <div className={'rightContainer'}>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Need Help :(

Comment: Check my answers @Kim. Hope that help you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make React Flexbox stretch to full screen height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361928/how-to-make-react-flexbox-stretch-to-full-screen-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***see patelarpan's answer for a easy way to do this***

You have to set the outermost container's height to 100%. Here is your fixed code(based on your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buckydroid/k31quu5w/))

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [{
          text: "Learn JavaScript",
          done: false
        },
        {
          text: "Learn React",
          done: false
        },
        {
          text: "Play around in JSFiddle",
          done: true
        },
        {
          text: "Build something awesome",
          done: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className={'container'}>
        
        <div className={'columnContainer'}>
            <div className={'leftContainer'}>

            </div>
            <div className={'middleContainer'}>

            </div>
            <div className={'rightContainer'}>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < TodoApp / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.columnContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftContainer {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.rightContainer {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.middleContainer {
  flex: 2;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this by using "vh" units, and it's a more effective way than using percentages because you don't need to set every parent height to 100% if you want the child's height to be 100%.

```
 .columnContainer { 
   display: flex; 
   height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

Here is an example of the 60px app bar height being excluded from the viewport height.

Comment: But this will give you problems with mobile devices where the keyboard makes the actual `vh` to change

Comment: Your answer here seems to apply to [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361928/how-to-make-react-flexbox-stretch-to-full-screen-height). Thanks for the concise solution!